# Removing country code from phone number

Tags: java, android, country-codes

I am stuck with a problem in which some contacts contain a country code while others don't.

I have code for fetching contact numbers which are being saved in list. The list looks like this:

```
[9999999999, 91-8888888888, 91-0000000000, 1111111111]
```

Now, I want to remove country code from those numbers which have it. I can't figure out a way to check this.

Here is my code for fetching contacts:

```
ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(); //Activity/Application android.content.Context
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        do
        {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            if(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{ id }, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    String contactName = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                    String contactNumber = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    allContacts.add(contactName);
                    contactNumber = contactNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    allnumbers.add(contactNumber);

                    break;
                }
                pCur.close();
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

    }
}
```

Here, `allnumbers` contains the number (where some have country code with them and others don't). How can I remove the country code from those who have it?

Any help or keywords to search will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Too less info. Where's your code?

Comment: Removing the country codes, if there is more than one in the file, makes the phone numbers meaningless. It might be better to supply a default country code for numbers that don't have one. For example, in North America, assume +1.

Comment: Do the country codes have the "+" sign?

Comment: Are you basically asking how to do string manipulatinos? If so, please read some tutorials about that. It's off-topic for SO.

Comment: no am using the number for matching something, and country codes making it impossible to match, so i need to remove country code. And yes it shows + sign in log

Comment: Well that's quite simple.. You can use `substring` method and extract the last 10 digits..  Only if length greater than zero and 10

Comment: Is it only the +91 you're wanting to remove? Because codes can vary e.g. +1 and +300, you're best to take all numbers and locations of the numbers then get the country code for them, this way you're not losing any information.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the first occurance of a string containing '91-', you could simply use the replaceFirst() method. So your code will end up like this:

```
contactNumber.replaceAll("\\s+","").replaceFirst("91-","");
```

If you want to check if a string starts with '91-', you could use this:

```
if (contactNumber.startsWith("91-")) {

}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score 0):

In your sample with array of numbers you have dash(-) between countrycode. So you can just use **indexOf** to determine if number has country code. You can do the same thing using regexp(`[\d]+-[\d]+`)

Also you can count degits. Usually numbers without country codes have only 10 digits. It depends on your situation

Answer (score -3):

Just try

```
contactNumber = contactNumber.replace("+91", "");
```

Hope this helps...